# Can a Horizon Walker ranger use the Distant Strike feature to teleport out of the Forcecage spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, ranger, teleportation

[Distant Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#DistantStrike-726) is a [Horizon Walker ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#HorizonWalker) feature which states (XGtE, p. 43):

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in a
>   blink of an eye. When you use the Attack action, you can teleport up
>   to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

The [*forcecage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) spell description states, in part:

> A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side,
>   creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through
>   it and blocking any spells cast into or out from the area.
>
> When you cast the spell, any creature that is completely inside the
>   cage’s area is trapped. Creatures only partially within the area, or
>   those too large to fit inside the area, are pushed away from the
>   center of the area until they are completely outside the area.
>
> A creature inside the cage can’t leave it by nonmagical means. If the
>   creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to leave the
>   cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the
>   creature can use that magic to exit the cage. On a failure, the
>   creature can’t exit the cage and wastes the use of the spell or
>   effect. The cage also extends into the Ethereal Plane, blocking
>   ethereal travel.

Can the ranger attack a location and thus teleport 10 feet outside the *forcecage*?

Comment: @sevensideddie so to be clear this isn't a duplicate?

Comment: It’s not clear to me yet. Are you hoping to attack with no enemy target involved? It kinda sounds like it.

Comment: @sevensideddie the question was focusing more on the teleporting part

Comment: Related: [Can you take the Attack action when not in range of an enemy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119450/can-you-take-the-attack-action-when-not-in-range-of-an-enemy), [Can creatures use the Attack action without attacking?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/can-creatures-use-the-attack-action-without-attacking)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Yes, but you need to make a Charisma saving throw

Distant Strike states that you:

> gain the ability to **pass between the planes** in a blink of an eye. When you use the Attack action, **you can teleport** up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

Forcecage states that:

> If the creature tries to use **teleportation** or **interplanar** travel to leave the cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw

Since the Ranger is attempting both teleportation and interplanar travel, so they must make a Charisma saving throw as per the rules for Forcecage.

Note that this is congruent with the general idea of the rules that *the specific overrules the general*. In most cases Distant Strike allows travel without a check, but the specific language of Forcecage adds this additional requirement.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, but you need to make a Charisma saving throw

I totally agree with [jgn's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/158203/12478) (I mean, I even copied their title) but I feel like there's a simpler way to prove it.

[Forcecage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) states :

> If the creature **tries to use teleportation** or interplanar travel **to leave the cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw**.

The Horizon Walker Ranger ability clearly establish :

> When you use the Attack action, you can **teleport** up to 10 feet

The ranger ability is a teleport and the spell explicitly state that to teleport outside the cage, you need a Charisma saving throw.

Comment: Thanks Nahyn Oklauq, I added this argument to my answer, good catch. I think I found the answer in the first sentence so I stopped looking for more :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes, they can attempt to teleport as part of their Attack action.

The Horizon Walker's Distant Strike lets them teleport when they take the Attack action. As part of [making an attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack), they can choose to attack a nearby enemy, or if there are none nearby, they can "attack" an empty location.

> Whether you're striking with a melee weapon, firing a weapon at range, or making an attack roll as part of a spell, an attack has a simple structure.
>
> 1. **Choose a target.** Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature,
>      an object, or a location.

Thus they can use the Attack action as a means of attempting escape. And unless something prevents them from performing attacks or taking the Attack action, the Horizon Walker can effectively use their Action at will to teleport up to (at least) 10 feet.

Note that teleportation effects, such as Distant Strike, have a chance to fail when inside a [*Forcecage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage):

> If the creature tries to use teleportation or interplanar travel to leave the cage, it must first make a Charisma saving throw. On a success, the creature can use that magic to exit the cage. On a failure, the creature can’t exit the cage and wastes the use of the spell or effect.

So when the ranger takes the Attack action and attempts to teleport, they must make a Charisma saving throw in order to teleport successfully. Otherwise the teleportation fails and they remain in the *Forcecage*.

Comment: This answer is the best currently because it specifically cites rules allowing the character to attack an object or location - meaning they don't need an enemy to attack outside the _forcecage_ in order to use the feature.