# Can you combine Pushing Attack with the Shield Master feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, combat-maneuver

Pushing attack activates with a weapon attack and Shield master is a bonus action to shove. Can these be combined to a 20' shove or would it have to be 15' shove followed by a 15' move and another 5' shove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No. You'll have to move to shove again.

Pushing Attack requires a weapon attack:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack...

A shove is not a weapon attack:

> Using the attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you.

As soon as you push the target with Pushing Attack, the creature is moved 15 feet, so you have to get within melee range to shove.

Comment: This answer confused me at first. I would clarify that the reason the move is needed is that, in addition to your answer, the effects are applied immediately. At the end of the Pushing Attack, the creature is now 15' away and you must move to be within melee range in order to shove the 5' with the shield. I suppose my confusion stems from the fact that I do not think the OP was suggesting that he could trigger Pushing Attack via Shield Master, but hoping he could execute both before the target actually moved.

Comment: @Joshua'sMu better?

Comment: I think that makes it explicitly clear, yes.

Comment: Having read https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/shield-master-can-the-shield-push-be-taken-before-an-attack and seeing that I can use the shove first I was wondering if a "special melee attack" equates to a "weapon attack".