# Can I use a bonus action before my action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, bonus-action

In D&D 5e can I use my bonus action before my action? For example if I wanted to cast *Ensnaring Strike* before my action to benefit from the bonus immediately.

Is this OK, or is a bonus action intended to be used after the action?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The rule for bonus actions says:

> You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn, unless the bonus action's timing is specified, and anything that deprives you of your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus action.

So unless the bonus action specifies that you have to take it at a specific time, you can take the bonus action at any point in your turn.

For an example of a bonus action which restricts the timing like this, check out the Monk's Flurry of Blows:

> Immediately **after** you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.

In the case of *Ensnaring Strike*, neither it specifically nor bonus action spells in general place any restrictions on timing, so you can cast it at any point in your turn.