# Does a Ranger with dual daggers and Two-Weapon Fighting make four attacks at full strength plus Hunter's Mark at level 5?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, balance, two-weapon-fighting

We have a Ranger who has taken Two-Weapon Fighting and wields dual daggers.  He is saying that this allows him to attack with both weapons as part of his Attack action.  He says that each of those attacks does 1d4(dagger) + 5(dex) + 1d6(hunter's mark) damage.  He is also saying that at level 5, he can do this twice a turn, for a total potential of 28–60 damage *every single turn*.

He says that he will be getting even more extra attacks at higher levels.  (Not sure where he is getting this from, and the PHB only says one extra.)

Summary:

- Does having two daggers with Two-Weapon fighting allow attacking with both in a single Attack action?
- Corollary to the above, does Extra Attack allow another attack where he can attack with both daggers again?
- Does he add the Dexterity modifier to every single hit?
- Does Hunter's Mark add 1d6 for every single hit?

Comment: @TimGrant, yeah I read that question first, but (probably because I do not understand the rules fully) it did not seem to answer the question I had.  Marq's question below I think is actually a really good answer to this question which covers slightly more than in the linked question.

Comment: Or at least, for me, his answer makes it easier to understand the rules than the other question.

Comment: @Infiltrator The dupe will answer your question on how many attacks they can actually make, but if you're still confused about adding the dexterity modifier and hunter's mark damage, I suggest asking 2 separate questions.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

Let's work through this piece by piece. To start with, here are some basic definitions:

- An **attack** is a single to-hit roll and a single damage roll (PHB, 
  p. 194).
- On a character's turn, they can take one **action**, and (if they have abilities that permit it) a single **bonus action** (PHB, p. 189).
- One of the actions a character may take is the **Attack**
  action, which allows them to make a single attack (as defined
  above) with a melee or ranged weapon (PHB, p. 192).

Here's the general rule for fighting with two weapons (PHB, p. 195):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

Here's the Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style (PHB p. 91):

> When you engage in two-weapon fighting, you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack.

Here's the ranger's Extra Attacks feature (PHB p. 91):

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

And here's the relevant parts of the *hunter's mark* spell (PHB, p. 251):

> **Casting Time**: 1 bonus action
>
> **Duration**: Concentration, up to 1 hour
>
> You choose a creature you can see within range and mystically mark it as your quarry. Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack ... If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

## So:

- The ranger can take the Attack action to make *two* attacks (one from taking an Attack action and one from Extra Attack). Each one (if it hits, and if the ranger used a dagger) will do 1d4 (dagger) + 5 (Dexterity) damage.
- If the ranger takes the Attack action, and they are wielding a dagger in their off-hand, they can use their bonus action to make *one* additional attack, also doing 1d4+5 damage. (The Two-Weapon fighting style allows them to add their Dexterity bonus to to damage).
- *Hunter's mark* takes a bonus action to cast or change targets. This means the ranger can't make a third (off-hand) attack on a turn when they cast it.
- *Hunter's mark* requires concentration to maintain, meaning the ranger needs to make a saving throw every time they take damage while concentrating on the spell (PHB, pp. 203-204).
- *Hunter's mark*  affects *one* target. The ranger won't get any damage bonus against other targets.

So, to answer your specific questions:

*Does having two daggers with Two-Weapon fighting allow attacking with both in a single action?* No. The Attack action allows a single attack, regardless of how many weapons are being held. Two-Weapon Fighting only affects how much damage is done with the bonus action attack, not the number of attacks that can be made.

*Corollary to the above, does Extra Attack allow another Attack action where he can attack with both daggers again?* No. He can make two attacks with a dagger instead of one. Attacking with the second dagger requires using a bonus action.

*Does he add the Dexterity modifier to the damage of every single hit?* Yes. That's what the benefit of Two-Weapon Fighting is.

*Does Hunter's Mark add 1d6 for every single hit?* Yes, for every hit on the creature that was the target of *hunter's mark* after it was cast.

On turns after the the turn when the ranger has used a bonus action to cast *hunter's mark*, they can make three attacks (using their action and bonus action) against the targeted creature, and each of those attacks will do 1d4+5+1d6 damage.

Comment: Just to clarify something, can you use your bonus action before your main action?  So can you cast Hunter's Mark first and then attack; or is it nerfed on the first turn (which seems unfair)?

Comment: Your last sentence seems to imply that the ranger can cast hunter's mark (bonus action), then attack, then make an offhand attack (another bonus action) - This would not be possible in one turn.

Comment: @Infiltrator you can find the answer to your question here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64157/23970

Comment: @Infiltrator Since this question is closed, you should ask that in another question, but, yes, you can use a bonus action before your regular action.

Comment: @patta I clarified; I meant on turns after the turn when Hunter's Mark was cast.

Answer (score 1):

> Does having two daggers with Two-Weapon fighting allow attacking with both in a single action?

No. The rules on Two-weapon fighting are found on Player's Handbook, page 195, and the off-hand attack costs a **bonus action** to make. The fighting style of the ranger simply improves the damage output of this off-hand attack.

However, having an extra attack allows him to make two attacks with a single action, and it's up to the ranger to decide what weapon gets used in each attack, so the ranger can choose to strike once with each dagger. This is not, by the rules, Two-weapon fighting and does not consume the ranger's bonus action, just the two attacks given by their normal action.

> Corollary to the above, does Extra Attack allow another Attack action where he can attack with both daggers again?

No, and extra attack doesn't grant extra actions anyway - it just makes you get one more attack from your action.

> Does he add the Dexterity modifier to every single hit?

The only case (apart from having unusual modifiers for a ranger) where the Ranger would not do so is if he was Two-weapon fighting without the fighting style, but since he has the Two-weapon style, he does indeed.

> Does Hunter's Mark add 1d6 for every single hit?

Yes, Hunter's Mark triggers whenever the ranger hits the target with a weapon attack, and off-hand attacks are weapon attacks.

### Summary

After getting their Extra attack, a ranger wielding light weapons can normally attack thrice per turn: two from their Attack action (including the extra attack) and once with their bonus action, as an offhand attack.

Comment: I would also ask how/why the OP thinks this particular Ranger will have MORE Extra Attacks at higher levels...which is not true unless the Ranger is multiclassing into high levels of Fighter.....

Comment: @Airatome from the Ranger player.