# Can the Polearm Master bonus attack only be used after the main attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, actions, bonus-action

The first benefit of the [Polearm Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/polearm-master) feat says (PHB, p. 168):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with only a glaive,
> halberd, quarterstaff, or spear, you can use a bonus action to make a
> melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon.

Does this additional attack clearly occur *after* the attack with the main weapon? Or is there a time to use it between the attack being "declared" and resolving the main attack?

Background/motivation: I would like to attempt the following:

1. Announce I am attacking Bandit Keith;
2. Use the bonus action to attack with my halberd's shaft, with a Tripping Attack maneuver;
3. Assuming success on the attack / STR check, attack with the halberd blade at advantage;

While that appears to fit how the flow of a fight works in my head, the word *take* appears a bit ambiguous to me if I wish to argue from RAW. If an action is *taken*, does this mean it must be completely resolved?

Comment: Technically, this question is not a duplicate of either the question it's currently closed as a dupe of nor the others linked in the comments. The correct answer to all of them uses the same logic, but the questions themselves are different. (Theoretically, they could all be duplicates of a canonical question like "If a bonus action says it can only be taken if/when a certain action is taken, do you have to take the action before the bonus action?", but such a question hasn't been asked; whether it's useful to do so may be worth asking on meta.) As such, I'm reopening this question.

Comment: Relevant meta: [If an answer to question A can be found in question B, should we close A as duplicate of B?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7523/33569). ...I found a slightly more related meta: [Is this question about bonus actions a duplicate?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6798/33569)

Comment: Closely related (but not duplicates): [Can you make a bonus-action attack from Two-Weapon Fighting before you take your action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131317/33569), [Can an Eldritch Knight use the bonus-action attack granted by War Magic before casting the spell as an action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72636/33569), [Bonus action before Action for Crossbow Expert?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95802/33569), [Shield Master - Can the shield push be taken before an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51525/33569)

Comment: One more: [Can I use a bonus action before my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64157/33569)

Comment: Also relevant: [Can you break up your Attack action for a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72888/15614).

Answer (score 5):

### After the Attack action is complete.

[Crawford has explained the intent of the rules](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/994993596989300736):

> Clarification about bonus actions: if a feature says you can do X as a bonus action if you do Y, you must do Y before you can do X.

In this case, your feat says:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with [...]

So you need to declare you're attacking Keith and conduct your attack(s). You can then use your bonus action attack with a Tripping Maneuver. After that, feel free to Action Surge and (hopefully) slam a prone Keith!

Consider that, if you could do this the other way around, you'd break the logic. If you did a BA attack first and killed your target, you would finish combat and no longer have anything to attack with your action, which would break the **when you take the Attack action and attack** condition.

This is very similar to the [Shield Master bonus attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/shield-master-can-the-shield-push-be-taken-before-an-attack), [Eldritch Knight](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72636/can-an-eldritch-knight-use-the-bonus-action-attack-granted-by-war-magic-before-c), and [Crossbow Expert](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95802/bonus-action-before-action-for-crossbow-expert) rulings, which have the same wording.

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow you are holding.

> If you take the Attack action on your turn, you can use a bonus action to try to shove a creature within 5 feet of you with your shield.

Quoting [Protonflux's answer from the Crossbow Expert question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95802/do-you-have-to-take-the-attack-action-before-you-can-make-the-bonus-action-attac/95809#95809):

> While this is perhaps not as clear as it could be, the order is implicit in the logic of the description: When you take the attack option (this must happen first for the condition to be satisfied) you can use a bonus action (therefore this must happen after taking the action).
>
> It would perhaps be better if it had been written: "then you can use a bonus action", but omitting the "then" does not change the fact that there is a when condition.

Answer (score 4):

### The order is unimportant, you take both attacks

When you take the attack action, you can choose which of the attacks is the 'bonus' attack, and you choose when it occurs.  Your are still taking the Attack action so you'll do both attacks.
This is directly supported by the rules on PHB page 189.

> **You choose when to take a bonus action during your turn**, unless the
> bonus action’s timing *is specified*, and anything that deprives you of
> your ability to take actions also prevents you from taking a bonus
> action.

The timing is ***not*** specified.  For an example of when the timing ***is*** specified, see the Monk's Flurry of Blows feature says, which specifies "after"

> *Immediately after* you take the Attack action on your turn, you can
> spend 1 ki point to make two unarmed strikes as a bonus action.

[Related Q&A are here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56060/22566).

The polearem master has no restriction; *when* does not mean *immediately after*.  If the Polearm Master feat had specified "immediately after" (as was done with the Monk) that would be different.  Such required sequencing was not specified.

#### Some notes on RAI and the confusion

That Jeremy Crawford has waffled on how the choice of when to take your bonus action influences feats like Shield Master (after two years of adhering to the original basis) is an unfortunate case of putting the twit into Twitter and thereby abandoning the core guidance for this edition of using plain English to interpret the rules.

His original point on sequencing was made [back in 2015](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/557816721810403329).

> @JeremyECrawford
> Jan 21, 2015
> As with most bonus actions, you choose the timing, so the Shield Master shove can come before or after the Attack action.

Two years later, for whatever reason, he changed his mind but the real problem with his waffling is that the rules as written allow for the choice of what happens in the combat turn - when you apply your bonus action - *unless otherwise specified*.  ([An interesting analysis of that is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59558/22566)).

#### So what do I do?

This brings us back to "rulings versus rules" - I suggest that you work with your DM and arrive at that which makes the most sense at your table.  And once the DM rules on it, go with that and don't look back.  If you have read a lot of J Crawford tweets over the years, as I have, you'll find a common refrain from him along the lines of: whatever gives you the most joy at your table.  Work with your DM.

Comment: I disagree that the wording distinction between those two allows you to resolve "If you do X, you can do Y" stuff in the reverse order - and I had always thought Crawford's initial ruling (that you could do Y first even if it was dependent on you doing X) was an illogical reading of the rules, so I don't think the fact that Crawford made that ruling first grants it any more "legitimacy" than his revised ruling. Also, his reasoning for the revised ruling was pretty clearly explained, even if you disagree with it:

Comment: ["In 2017, I changed the ruling on bonus action timing because the old ruling was illogical. The original ruling failed to account for the fact that X relying on Y is a form of timing. The new ruling corrects that oversight."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/995069135905161216) (...sorry for this taking up multiple comments; they're wordy tweets, so more than one tweet quote+link doesn't fit in one comment :P)

Comment: And: ["The old ruling on bonus action timing didn't quiet questions on that timing. Instead, the illogical ruling fueled questions, and it even inadvertently led some fans to think our choice of words like "if" or "when" had super-precise meanings in bonus actions. They don't."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/995080418834636800)

Comment: And: ["My ruling on bonus action timing has nothing to do with the balance of Shield Master or any other feature that gives you a bonus action. It's about being able to read bonus actions in a natural way, not with an external ruling clouding things."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/995108600161824768) ...Anyway, I'm just pointing this out because the answer says: "for whatever reason, he changed his mind". His reasoning for revising the ruling is logic I agreed with (and disagreed with his original ruling on) even before the revision. Just figured you might find the tweets useful.

Comment: @V2Blast I do not agree with  his logic.  The whole point of shield master is that you incorpoarte the shield into the six second round/turn. You burn an ASI to get this ability. It becomes a part of your offense and your defense.  So you shove with it either at the beginnin or at the end.  It can happen any time in the six second round.  Think "300" and how the spartans used the shield offensively. (Also, I've seen it at SCA events over the years).  It is really disingenuous of JC to have all of these abstractions, and then all of a sudden get granular. Lame excuse from JC remains lame.

Comment: I think it's a badly designed feat because of the way it's worded, and should be errataed to allow shoving first (or being conditional on a single attack instead of on the Attack action as a whole) - but it being badly designed doesn't affect whether I think "If X, then Y" means you can do Y without having done X yet. Anyway, just wanted to point out the reasoning he gives, since it's there. Thanks for the discussion. :)

Comment: What if you kill your target with th BA attack? You can no longer make the attack that triggers the BA attack

Comment: @BlueMoon93 there is no rule against hitting a creature that is already down, I don't get your point.   You can either attack something else, in any case you have still taken the attack action, and you can even hit the downed creature with advantage since it is prone and trigger two failed death saves ... there are a variety of things that you can do. Widen your field of view.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the rational for disallowing these types of bonus actions to occur before completing the requisite action rests on the consideration that some circumstances may remove the qualifying action from coming into play. For example using a bonus action shield bash to shove your only opponent over a cliff removes the opportunity to follow up with an attack action. I don't find this to be sufficient rational to restrict the order of application. It seems *enough* that by using such a bonus action you have effectively committed to using your action in the requisite way. If you can no longer do so or choose not to, **you simply lose your action**. That is the cost of using a bonus action that requires your action to be used in a particular way.
This seems to me to be the fairest application of these rules and affords the player choice without undue benefit.