# Path of the Beast: Can I shove then make the bonus claw attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, barbarian

One of Path of the Beast feature is:

> Each of your hands transforms into a claw, which you can use as a weapon if it’s empty. It deals 1d6 slashing damage on a hit. **Once on each of your turns when you attack with a claw using the Attack action, you can make one additional claw attack as part of the same action.**

If I take Attack action and shove instead of normal attack, can I use the additional claw attack? Shove is an attack, too, right?

> Using the Attack action, you can make a Special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this Attack replaces one of them.

Comment: Perhaps related: "[Can I "shove" with a reach weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51209)" and "[Can you shove (Attack Action), attack (Extra Attack) and use Polearm Master's bonus action attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124390)" and "[Is "Shove" an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169617)"

Answer (score 16):

#### Only if you're level 5 or higher, and the other attack is a claw attack.

In short, if you're level 5 or higher and thus have the Extra Attack class feature, you have two attacks whenever you have the Attack Action. If you spend one of those Attacks to Shove and one to attack with a claw, then you'll trigger the bonus of the Path of the Beast Feature, allowing you to make an additional Claw attack as part of that Attack Action. The shove itself is a "special melee attack" that doesn't use any weapons, so it will not in itself trigger the additional claw attack.

Comment: So a shove attack while the claws are out doesn't count as an attack made with a claw?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson It's a special melee attack that doesn't make use of any weapons. I suppose I can edit my answer to explicitly state that.