# Does the Haste spell's hasted action allow you to make multiple unarmed strikes? Or none at all?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, actions, unarmed-combat

The [Haste](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell states that you can

> **take the Attack (one weapon attack only)**, Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

(emphasis mine)

But we know that "weapon attacks" and "melee weapon attacks" are different, since weapon attacks require the use of an actual weapon, while unarmed strikes are classified as melee weapon attacks, and cannot use things like Booming Blade or Thunderous Smite as you don't have a physical weapon.

Since it says "only", does that disqualify a hasted character from using an Unarmed Strike as an attack (as it's not a weapon attack)? Or does it allow the character to instead make the usual number of attacks they can make if they use an Unarmed Strike (because of the same reasoning)?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58158/is-an-unarmed-strike-considered-a-weapon-attack

Answer (score 20):

## *Haste* allows one additional Unarmed Strike

The reasoning is present in your own question; *haste* states that you can:

> take the Attack (one **weapon attack** only)

And you point out that:

> weapon attacks require the use of an actual weapon, while unarmed strikes are classified as melee **weapon attacks**.

Given that [an unarmed strike is a melee weapon attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88865/35259), and that's exactly what *haste* allows, then unarmed strikes qualify for the extra attack granted by *haste*.

However, you would still only be able to make one additional unarmed strike, just the same as if you were making attacks with a weapon, since *haste* explicitly says "**one** weapon attack only".

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer by pointing out that attacks are divided into four categories along two axis.  Attacks are always either a spell attack or a weapon attack, a ranged attack or a melee attack.  Unarmed strikes aren't spell attacks, so they *have* to be weapon attacks, as well as melee weapon attacks, which means they're melee attacks too.

Comment: @ronlugge this is not true, such as with grapple/shove which are neither weapon nor spell attacks. Though I do believe they are the only exception to your four-way chart there are other things the books use when describing attacks such as specifying the *type of weapon* that needs to be used and not the type of attack. see this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149651/is-this-attack-type-chart-correct