# Can you really not grapple/shove using the Haste spell's Attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

The [*haste*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste) spell's description states:

> it gains an additional action on each of its turns. That action can be used only to take the **Attack (one weapon attack only)**, Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

When looking at this Q/A ("[Does the *haste* spell's hasted action allow you to make unarmed strikes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153626/does-the-haste-spells-hasted-action-allow-you-to-make-multiple-unarmed-strikes)") I realized grapple/shove state:

> You can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack...

Both of them are considered melee attacks but are not weapon attacks. Does this really mean you cannot grapple or shove when taking *haste's* Attack action?

Note: I am asking this even though it seems clear to me that you cannot grapple/shove through *haste* because perhaps (hopefully) there is some specific exception I've missed somewhere.